# Getting RowID after inserting in Room Persistence Library Android Studio

Tags: java, android, database, android-room

I've been using the [codelabs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-persistence/#7) for my Room Database Persistence. Now I am trying to get the latest rowID after inserting data into my room database. However, I am stuck in my repository trying to return the rowID from my AsyncTask.

LogEntity.java

```
@Entity
public class LogEntity {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;
```

LogDao.java

```
public interface LogDao {
    @Insert
    long insert(LogEntity logEntity);
```

LogDatabase.java

```
@Database(entities = LogEntity.class, version = 1)
public abstract class LogDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    private static LogDatabase instance;
    public abstract  LogDao logDao();

    public static synchronized LogDatabase getInstance(Context context){
        if (instance == null){
            instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                    LogDatabase.class, "log_database").
                    fallbackToDestructiveMigration().build();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

LogRepository.java

```
    public long insertLogs(LogEntity logEntity) {
        new InsertLogAsyncTask(logDao).execute(logEntity);
        return **
    }
    private static class InsertLogAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<LogEntity, Void, Long>{
        private LogDao logDao;
        private InsertLogAsyncTask(LogDao logDao){
            this.logDao = logDao;
        }
        @Override
        protected Long doInBackground(LogEntity... logEntities) {
            logDao.insert(logEntities[0]);
            return logDao.insert(logEntities[0]);
        }
    }
```

I put two asterisks because I'm not sure what to do here in order to get the insert RowID and whether my AsyncTask is completely correct.

LogViewModel.java

```
    public long insertLog(LogEntity logEntity){
        return repository.insertLogs(logEntity);
    }
```

MainActivity.java

```
        long id = logViewModel.insertLog(logEntity);
```

I want to be able to use this final id variable for future use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track but not quite there.
You should declare the AsyncTask class as an inner class of the ViewModel and not the DB.

In the ViewModel add an ID variable and in the AsyncTask add the `onPostExecute` override to handle the execution result.

LogViewModel.java

```
long mLastInsertedID;

private static class InsertLogAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<LogEntity, Void, Long>{
    private LogDao logDao;
    private InsertLogAsyncTask(LogDao logDao){
        this.logDao = logDao;
    }
    @Override
    protected Long doInBackground(LogEntity... logEntities) {
        //you are now off the UI thread
        logDao.insert(logEntities[0]);
        return logDao.insert(logEntities[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
        //Do whatever you like with the result as you are back on the UI thread
        mLastInsertedID = result;
    }
}
```