# Android Room Java - Right way to insert data when the rowId / Primary Key of the new row is required

Tags: java, android, insert, android-room, primary-key

In my app (MVVM architecture) I am inserting a new row to a table. In the next step I want to use the newly generated Primary Key as identifier for a notification.

My initial approach (based on my limited experience) was to insert the row asynchronously as described in many tutorials. In the next step I used a LiveData parameter to get the max rowId from the table (which is a good approach for various queries...). But obviously that does not work in this case, as the timestamp of the onChanged event in my observer is earlier as the asynchronous insert task is finished. Therefore I have the "old" max rowId. So I have to look for other solutions.

It seems there are multiple solutions for my problem.

Mainly I have found the follwoing two / three approaches:

- Adding a callback to the Async-Task for inserting a new row
  (see [SQLite MVVM return & obtain rowId in Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60056024/sqlite-mvvm-return-obtain-rowid-in-activity))
- Moving the Async-Task for Insert to the View Model and perform an action onPostExecute
  (see [Getting RowID after inserting in Room Persistence Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56354433/getting-rowid-after-inserting-in-room-persistence-library-android-studio))
- One user (anser in the first link) reccommends not to use Async-Task for this operation (I did not think more in detail about this solution...)

From what I understand is the worst approach to perform CRUD operations on the main thread.

I personally like the solution without the callback function, but this requires to move the Async-Task into the View-Model, which I do not really like. With that solution, I cannot reuse the function in any other activity / fragment without duplicating the code. Therefore I would prefer to have this code in the repository.

Can anybody advice what is the cleanest / best way to solve this issue?

Comment: Google recommendations are listed here https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/async-queries
We are talking about "One-shot writes (with a return value, that would be the ID/primary key being returned). Since you are using Java only (not Kotlin), their recommendations all need an additional library (JavaRx or Guava), which might or might not work for you.